# Very long words (e.g. in URLs) in edit summaries don't wrap, causing horizontal scroll bars to appear

Tags: bug, status-review, design, suggested-edits

I came across this when I saw [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33381221) on my phone, and saw that there was a horizontal scroll bar due to a long URL in the edit summary:

[image]

---

To better reproduce the bug I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33417273) while not logged in to [How to avoid splitting float numbers while using Wordninja?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74804599/1364007). In the inline suggested edit review view it looks like this, with the text overflowing and causing a horizontal scroll bar:

[image]

In the 'proper' review view it looks similar, again with the text overflowing and appearing behind the list of actions:

[image]

The last two screenshots are with a Chrome 108.0.5359.99 window on Windows 11 at 1398px wide, which is wider than the ~1100px at which Stack Overflow stops filling the available horizontal space.

Admittedly my suggested edit was a bit of a contrived example, but the first example was not.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 107.0.1, but only when the window gets very narrow. It's not as aggressive as what you're seeing in the last screenshot, but it's most definitely present: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R0Xt.png - reproduced with window widths under ~700px

Comment: Ah, so you're the anonymous user who put `https://example.com/IImagineThatThisVeryLongUrlWillHopefullyDemonstrateAStrangeBugThatICameAcrossOnStackOverflowWhileDoingASuggestedEditsReviewTaskTheOtherDayIfNotIWillUseAnotherUrlInsteadIWillPostABugReportOnMetaStackOverflowAboutItThough` in my review queue.

Comment: I am actually on the fence if I would call this a problem. I mean yeah sure it looks hilariously broken, but in the end it's just an unreadable URL... that is only taking up one line of space instead of several. The gain outweighs the broken look, IMO :)